WSO2 API Manager Unable to Create APIs After Configuration with Oracle Database
We have tried to configure wso2 apimanager api details into Oracle db. For that we have done below configuration on deployment .toml file
[database.apim_db]
type = "oracle"
url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcljegan"
username="AMDB"
password="finexta123"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"

[database.shared_db]
type = "oracle"
url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcljegan"
username="SHAREDDB"
password="finexta123"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"

And I have executed all the oracle base dbscripts given by wso2 product which is present in below loaction "wso2am-4.2.0\dbscripts"
After restart API manager is running successfully but in the developer portal we have tried to create an API in wso2 api manager and i have faced the view doesn't exit issue in the console and API also not created. Its failing to create api.

Need to configure Oracle db and store the API values into oracle database. How to achieve that can anyone help for this

I recommend reviewing the error log to determine which specific table is missing. You can then log into the Oracle database to verify whether the table actually exists. If the table is absent in the Oracle database but included in the APIM's provided DB scripts, there may have been errors during the script execution that prevented the table from being created.
